Removing Blue Border from button when clicked Oracle APEX
I currently have card region on my oracle APEX page with a full card action that is set to the Redirect to URL.  Whenever I click a card, a blue border shows up around the card and I would like to have this removed if possible.
From what I can tell this is the same blue border that shows up around a button when you click it, but I have tried editing the outline CSS attribute with the following class .no-border-btn { outline: none !important; } and calling it in the Card Appearance and the link attributes fields with no luck.
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

APEX uses css variables since 22.1 to determine all the colors of all the components (google it, you'll find a couple of blogs). The trick is to find the css class that is causing that specific behaviour and then overriding it.
In the case of the blue line when a full card action is clicked, the class is "--a-cv-focus-border-color". To change that, put the following in Page attributes > CSS > Inline:
:root {   
  --a-cv-focus-border-color: none;
}

In this case I set it to none, so there is no more color on click, you'll still see some highlighting. Use any color code if you want to have another color.
